# Pagination error in Commontator Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I have used 'Commontator' gem in my rails application. I have done pagination in my discussions tab. Pagination allows 10 comments in one page. There are links when we want to do on next page for reading more comments. 
When I click on next link, it takes me to Page 2, but when I open that link in new tab, it show me an error :
`undefined method 'api_path' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::RoutesProxy:0xe45a768>`

I tried searching for the solution but could not find any.

Pagination links image : [image: pagination]

Error Image: [image: Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this answer after trying so much of coding. 
I understood everytime i open link in new tab, it use to search for polymorphic_path but was not able to find one. 
Then in threads_controller. I changed the code with following:

```
if comment.thread.commontable_type == "Api"
  main_app.api_show_url(api_name:comment.thread.commontable.name)
elsif comment.thread.commontable_type == "Product"
  main_app.company_url(comment.thread.commontable.product_name)
end
```

This code will first check if the thread is for API or for Product model. then accordingly it will call the show method for that model.